# Path for css font face

Tags: css

So this is the path of my fonts: project->assets->css->fonts, and in the fonts folder are my font files. I've tried this way:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ralewaythin';
  src: url('assets/css/fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.svg') etc
```

But I really sucks at paths. Sorry if this is really stupid, but I really can't understand them

Comment: `src: url('assets/css/fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.svg')`

Comment: `src: url('./assets/css/fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.svg')` or check
`src: url('../assets/css/fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.svg')`

Comment: Where is your css file located compared to assets dir?

Comment: it doesn't work... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Relative URLs are allowed and are relative to the URL of the stylesheet (not to the URL of the web page).

Quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url).

So if you are using relative paths, be aware of the path of your `.css` file. Assuming your file is also in the `assets/css` directory, most probably the correct path would be:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ralewaythin';
    src: url('fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.svg');
    ...
}
```

But an absolute url is also perfectly fine (also not advised). So `http://www.yoursite/assets/css/fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.svg` should work as well.

Comment: http://www.yoursite/assets/css/fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.svg  tried this way, it works. Thank youuu

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass **reference/relative path** from when your CSS file is exist. not a project path. so your src url should be

```
url('fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.svg')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the correct path in which you are font files are sitting. The path may be relative to your .css file. While working on all projects if you can follow standard folder structure, it won't confuse much. If you are using Google font CDN or any other live link, you need not bother about local file path.